# combining an empty "master" df with multiple dynamically produced dfs built from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have the following code. I am trying to build a "master" df that holds the collective information from several created dfs which are created from nested dictionaries. I tried to use a dict to df conversion but it didn't work the way I wanted it too. I also would prefer the names of the columns to be created dynamically if possible.

```
masterDf = pd.DataFrame(columns =["Sprinter"])

for key, value in sprintingTimesDict.items():
    Sprinter = key
    sprinterList.append(Sprinter )
    for distance, sprintStats in sprintingTimesDict[key].items():       
        distanceList.append(distance)
        time = sprintStats["time"]
        timeList.append(time)
        acceleration= sprintStats["acceleration"]
        accelerationList.append(acceleration).......


    df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([sprinter,time, acceleration....]),columns =["sprinter", f"{distance}mtime", f"{distance}macceleration"....])
    print(df)
    masterDf = masterDf.merge(df,how='outer', left_on="Ticker")
```

print(masterDf)

this is a sort of example of the individual dfs produced

```
sprinter    100mtime    100macceleration    200mtime    200macceleration
x   10.5    0.75    21  0.90
sprinter    100mtime    100macceleration    200mtime    200macceleration
y   12.3    0.20    24.6    1.00
sprinter    100mtime    100macceleration    200mtime    200macceleration
z   9.83    0.63    19.66   0.30
```

The goal is to have them merge into one df like the one below.

```
sprinter    100mtime    100macceleration    200mtime    200macceleration
x   10.5    0.75    21  0.90
y   12.3    0.20    24.6    1.00
z   9.83    0.63    19.66   0.30
```

Currently my code produces the following output:

```
sprinter    100mtime    100macceleration    200mtime    200macceleration
x   10.5    0.75    21  0.90
y   12.3    NaN NaN NaN
y   NaN 0.20    NaN NaN
y   NaN NaN 24.6    NaN
y   NaN NaN NaN 0.30
z   9.83    NaN NaN NaN
z   NaN 0.63    NaN NaN
z   NaN NaN 19.66   NaN
z   NaN NaN NaN 0.30
```

Comment: Instead of an outer merge in each iteration, try creating a list before the for loop -> `master_df_list = []` at the end of each iteration append the `df` to the list ->  `master_df_list.append(df)` then after the for loop has finished concat the list of dataframes together -> `masterDf = pd.concat(master_df_list)`

Comment: This produces the same result

Comment: It is a bit unclear, however, (given that no sample of `sprintingTimesDict` was given) that if each iteration produces a dataframe with a single row, and none of the dataframe functions are used on `df` why you couldn't just build a nested list or a `dict` to use as the frame constructor. Or even create the frame directly from `sprintingTimesDict`

Comment: create minimal working code with example data in code - maybe problem is different then you think.

Comment: Hi!! Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed)

Answer (score 0):

After merging you can do:

```
df=df.groupby('sprinter',as_index=False).sum()
```

**OR**

If there are multiple different dtypes you can do:

```
df=df.groupby('sprinter',as_index=False).first()
```

output of `df`:

```
 sprinter   100mtime    100macceleration    200mtime    200macceleration
0   x       10.50       0.75                21.00           0.9
1   y       12.30       0.20                24.60           0.3
2   z       9.83        0.63                19.66           0.3
```